# Positive definite and block matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Suppose a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is positive definite.
Its block matrix form is written as follow.
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{M} \; = \; 
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B}\\
       \mathbf{B}^{T} & \mathbf{D}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Under what conditions can we say that the square matrices $\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{D}$ are also positive definite?

Comment: Every principal submatrix of a positive (semi)definite matrix is positive (semi)definite.

Comment: Related post where it instead asks when is $M$ positive definite: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280671/definiteness-of-a-general-partitioned-matrix-mathbf-m-left-beginmatrix-bf.

Answer (score 3):

As Algebraic Pavel stated correctly:

> Every principal submatrix of a positive (semi)definite matrix is positive (semi)definite.

Here some elaborate statements:

If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite, then all of its principal submatrices $a_{1:m,1:m}$ ($m=1,\dots, n$) are positive definite. If $A$ is positive semi-definite, then all of its principal submatrices $a_{1:m,1:m}$ ($m=1,\dots, n$) are positive semi-definite.

This also works for negative (semi)-definite matrices, by simply multiplying the matrix by -1, i.e.

If $-A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite, then all of its
principal submatrices $-a_{1:m,1:m}$ ($m=1,\dots, n$) are positive
definite. If $-A$ is positive semidefinite, then all of its principal
submatrices $-a_{1:m,1:m}$ ($m=1,\dots, n$) are positive semidefinite.

For a reference, see Observation 7.1.2 from Matrix Analysis (Horn, Johnson), 2nd edition.

See also [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), which is a similar statement regarding principle *minors*.