# How do I prove that all the eigenvalues are positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Show that the matrix
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\
> 0 & 2^2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\
> 0 & 0 & 2^3 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2^{n-1} & 1\\
> 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & a\\
> \end{bmatrix}
>
> only has positive eigenvalues if $a\ge 1.$

What should I use to prove this? Should I use the fact that the matrix is symmetric?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Symmetry shows that the eigenvalues are real, but not that they're positive.  Google "Sylvester's criterion"

Comment: Yes but the with symmetry i can if pivots are postitive and then its positive definite and therefore all eigenvalues are positive? Or is this true?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  That's why I thought of Sylvester's criterion.

Comment: Oh ty mate i will look in to it

Answer (score 2):

$M$ is symmetric, which means that it will have positive eigenvalues if and only if it is positive definite. We can write this matrix as
$$
M = \pmatrix{D & x\\x^T & a},
$$
where
$$
D = \pmatrix{2\\ &\ddots \\&& 2^{n-1}}, \quad x = \pmatrix{1 \\ \vdots \\ 1}.
$$
It is clear that $D$ is positive definite since it is diagonal with positive diagonal entries. Thus, $M$ will be positive definite if and only if the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness) $M/D$ is positive definite. We compute
$$
M/D = a - x^TD^{-1}x = a - (2^{-1} + \cdots + 2^{-(n-1)}) = a - \left(1 - 2^{-n}\right).
$$
Thus, we find that the matrix $M$ is positive definite if and only if $a > (1 - 2^{-n})$.

We can therefore see that $M$ will be positive definite for **all** integers $n \geq 1$ if and only if
$$
a \geq \sup_{n \geq 1} (1 - 2^{-n}) = 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

A cyclic permutation matrix takes the original (by congruence) into something more pleasant, I am calling it $H.$ . I took $a=1.$  The matrix I call $Q$ is upper triangular, all entries $\pm 1,$ with the main diagonal  and the first row are all $+1,$  the rest of the upper triangle is $-1$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Let's see, if $a > 1,$ we are simply adding my positive definite matrix $H$ below to a rank one semidefinite matrix $S,$ the single nonzero entry being $S_{11} = a-1.$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 2 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 8 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 2 &  - 4 &  - 8 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 8 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 16 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 32 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 2 &  - 4 &  - 8 &  - 16 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 32 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Answer (score 1):

I would personally endorse a caveman like approach to this.

Assume $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $\textbf{x} = (x_1, \dots x_n)$ is an eigenvector. Let's see what we get from the equation $Ax = \lambda x$ where $A$ is the matrix you've given.
We get the equations
\begin{align*}
2x_1 + x_n &= \lambda x_1  \ \ \  \ \ \ \Longrightarrow x_1 = \ \frac{x_n}{\lambda -2}\\
2^2x_2 + x_n &= \lambda x_2 \ \ \ \ \ \  \Longrightarrow x_2 = \frac{x_n}{\lambda -2^2}\\ 
& \ \  \vdots \ \\
2^{n-1}x_{n-1} + x_n &= \lambda x_{n-1} \ \ \Longrightarrow x_{n-1} = \frac{x_n}{\lambda -2^{n-1}} \\ \
\end{align*}

and lastly, we can use the above equations to obtain the following: $$ x_1  + \dots + ax_n  = \lambda x_n \ \  \Longrightarrow \frac{x_n}{(\lambda -2)} + \frac{x_n}{(\lambda -2^2)} + \dots \frac{x_n}{(\lambda -2^{n-1})} + a= \lambda x_n $$
The above equations imply that if $x_n = 0$ then $x_1 = \dots = x_{n-1} = 0$. So $\textbf{x}$ is the $0$ vector in which case **x** is not an eigenvector. So we may assume $x_n \neq 0$ and we can divide by $x_n$. We obtain

$$\frac{1}{(\lambda -2)} + \frac{1}{(\lambda -2^2)} + \dots \frac{1}{(\lambda -2^{n-1})} + a= \lambda   $$

If $a \geq 1$, then we have

$$\lambda - \frac{1}{(\lambda -2)} - \frac{1}{(\lambda -2^2)} - \dots  -\frac{1}{(\lambda -2^{n-1})}  = a\geq 1$$

from which we conclude

$$\lambda \geq 1+  \frac{1}{(\lambda -2)} + \frac{1}{(\lambda -2^2)} + \dots \frac{1}{(\lambda -2^{n-1})} $$

If $\lambda \leq 0$, this isn't possible. Geometric series shows the RHS is bounded below by $1/2^n$ if $\lambda \leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the matrix is symmetric, it has positive eigenvalues if and only if it is positive definite.  By [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) this is true if and only if all the leading principal minors are positive.  This is clearly true of the first $n-1$ of them, so we must prove that the matrix itself has positive determinant.  Write the matrix as $$M = \begin{bmatrix}D &x\\x^T & a\end{bmatrix},$$ where $$D = \begin{bmatrix}2\\ &\ddots \\&& 2^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}, \quad x = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Let $$U=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\-x^tD^{-1}&1\end{bmatrix},$$ where $I$ is an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ identity matrix.  We have $\det(U)=1$, since $U$ is lower triangular, with $1$'s on the diagonal.  Then $$\det(M)=\det(UM)=\det\begin{bmatrix}D&x\\0&a-x^tD^{-1}x\end{bmatrix}=2^{n(n-1)/2}(a-2^{1-n}),$$ so that $a\geq1$ implies $\det(M)>0$ for $n\geq2$.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280671/definiteness-of-a-general-partitioned-matrix-mathbf-m-left-beginmatrix-bf), if $\mathbf M=\left[\begin{matrix}\bf A & \bf b\\\bf b^\top & \bf d \\\end{matrix}\right]$ then $\det(\mathbf M)=\alpha\det(\mathbf A)$ where $\alpha=\mathbf d-\bf b^\top A^{-1}b$

In our case: $b^\top=[1,1, \cdots 1]$ and $ \alpha = a - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^{-k}$. Then, $a>1 \implies \alpha >0$  and the matrix is positive definite ([Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)) , and the eigenvalues are positive.